# Hashfunction of a hex value not a string in crypto-js

Tags: javascript, sha256, hash-function

Say I need to get the SHA-256 hash of 0xF0FD93 as a hex value not a string.

```
var SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');
hash = SHA256(0xF0FD93);
console.log(hash.toString()); //4ea5c508a6566e76240543f8feb06fd457777be39549c4016436afda65d2330e
```

I should get *a2ad9b3ba41abb6e4e4cafa6467efe65f58f0fb9a01b0f96c6548188ded27356* according to this http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/hashcalc/index.

edit I solved it:

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')

var message = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('F0FD93');
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(message);
console.log(hash.toString()); // a2ad9b3ba41abb6e4e4cafa6467efe65f58f0fb9a01b0f96c6548188ded27356

var wrongMessage = ('F0FD93');
var wrongHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(wrongMessage);

console.log(wrongHash.toString()); //c55b21323979adf4f963998e272827739a86ddeb8afc85b4e5dea3cdef7274be
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight - you want the hash value of the number 0xF0FD93 (15793555 in decimal)? JS should just convert your `0xF0FD93` into `15793555` when it comes to it, AFAIK so it might be doing that. Yet, I can't actually figure out what that result you're getting is - doing a SHA256 on `15793555` [here](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) gives me a different result, so I'm not sure what's happening there.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I think js sees my input as "0xF0FD93" not as the actual number.And yes I mean taking the hash of the number 15793555

Comment: No its a number. Maybe one of the implementations is wrong or has a different encoding